# Actiobar Sherlock and ViewPager Left Menu Not coming full Screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock, slidingdrawer

I am using Actionbar Sherlock and Viewpager in order to implement sliding menu.
Whenever i slide my menu it is not **overlapping** the view of fragment or the title like Gmail.

Here is the code for 
**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);
    title = new String[] { "Title 1", "Title 2",
    "Title 3" };
    subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle  1", "Subtitle  2",
                    "Subtitle  3" };
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
        GravityCompat.START);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.bar_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
    mDrawerLayout,
    R.drawable.ic_drawer,
    R.string.drawer_open,
    R.string.drawer_close
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

Here is the xml of **drawer_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I don't have 10+ reputation in order to post image on this site,so hosting in
imgur. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOwnH.jpg

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw the image I felt like you added more `scrollScale` to the fragment.
try decreasing the scale. for demo go through https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/ and try changing properties

Comment: Thanks Shranabasu. let me check once.